# Area Chart X-Axis Not Displaying

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating an area chart via matplotlib and the x-axis labels (index) are not being displayed. Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def graphing():


    data2 = [(12.20, 14.50, 15.60, 24.80),
         (11.30, 8.70, 23.20, 10.0),
         (6.40, 10.70, 22.60, 11.60),
         (15.0, 16.0, 23.40, 10.8)]

    columns = ["Expense Management", "Guidance", "Interest Rate and Deposit Costs", "Loan Growth"]

    index = ["2019Q3", "2019Q2", "2019Q1", "2018Q4"]

    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=data2, index=index, columns=columns)

    graph2 = df2.plot.area(stacked='True')

    graph2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    plot.show(block=True)


graphing()
```

I've added lines such as 'graph2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)' and it sill won't display my index labels. Any thoughts on what I can do?

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? Did you try to update?

Comment: Not sure which version I'm on, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
graph2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
```

[image]

**Edit after comment**:
Sorry, I'm unable to recreate your issue. For me the below code is working without issue:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def graphing():


    data2 = [(12.20, 14.50, 15.60, 24.80),
         (11.30, 8.70, 23.20, 10.0),
         (6.40, 10.70, 22.60, 11.60),
         (15.0, 16.0, 23.40, 10.8)]

    columns = ["Expense Management", "Guidance", "Interest Rate and Deposit Costs", "Loan Growth"]

    index = ["2019Q3", "2019Q2", "2019Q1", "2018Q4"]

    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=data2, index=index, columns=columns)

    graph2 = df2.plot.area(stacked='True')

    graph2.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    graph2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)

    plot.show(block=True)


graphing()
```

Comment: I tried this with this code, and I have the above result. Please post your result with this line added. Did you see I have a `x` in my added line of code and not `y` as you mentioned in your code.

Comment: Yes, I meant 'x' in my original post, I've since edited that. My graph output looks just like yours, I just don't have the '2019Q3', 2019Q2', etc